# How to zip a file that is generated in the code (Java)

Tags: java, file, oop, zip, directory

Well I'm generating 2 .xml files, but I want to save them in a folder, and also zip them, I don't want to generate them separately, but separated in a folder and zipped. d
Did you get that?

I want to put both of the files that I'm creating into a folder and zip it. The only thing that I want to save is the zip file.

```
String name = fields.find(chooser.getLocation(), "mimic");
                Mimic mimic = getMimic(mimicList.get(0));
                String fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString() + File.separator + "des_" +nombreMimic.substring(0, nombreMimic.length()-4)+ ".xml";
                String config = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString() + File.separator + "cfg_" +nombreMimic.substring(0, nombreMimic.length()-4)+".xml";
                FileOutputStream file;
                FileOutputStream file2;


                file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                file2 =new FileOutputStream(config);

                Parser parser;
                parser = new Parser(file,new String[]{});
                parser.render(mimic , fields);
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Complete!");

                Parser2 parser2;
                parser2 = new Parser2(file2,new String[]{});
                parser2.render(mimic , fields);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Complete!");   


                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString() + File.separator + "des_" +nombreMimic.substring(0, nombreMimic.length()-4)+ ".xml");
                ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(nombreMimic.substring(0, nombreMimic.length()-4)+".des"));

                zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));

                byte [] buffer = new byte [1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while((bytesRead=inputStream.read(buffer))>0){

                zip.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);

                }

                zip.closeEntry();
                zip.close();
                inputStream.close();


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error parsing");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Java 7?

Comment: no VERY PREVIOUS. Update is not an option, this is gonna be integrated in other stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the answer to your problem was answered here: [how to zip a folder itself using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968883/how-to-zip-a-folder-itself-using-java)

There it is explained how to zip a file/folder using Java.

You have to save the files in the folder for this to work, but once it is zipped, you can delete the original folder following this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html) which uses:

```
String path = "/path/to/file";
Files.delete(path);
```

This way the only thing saved will be the zip file.