# How to add folder to zip

Tags: java, gwt

I have my GWT project and I want to upload files to server. I want the following algorithm to work

1) create a folder with the name from "userNumber"

2) write uploaded files to this folder

3) add folder to zip

4) delete folder (if exists)

As I write on the server side I think it is just java problem. Here is my code. I can perform only the first and the second steps, i.e. I can create a folder and write files to this folder.

```
 @Override
    public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request,
            List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {
        String response = "";
        userNumber = request.getParameter("userNumber");
        File f = new File(ConfAppServer.getRealContextPath() + "/edoc/"
                + userNumber);
        if (f.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Directory Created");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Directory is not created");
        }
        for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
            if (false == item.isFormField()) {
                try {
                    String extension = item.getName().substring(
                            item.getName().length() - 3);
                    File file = null;
                    file = new File(ConfAppServer.getRealContextPath()
                            + "/edoc/"
                            + userNumber
                            + System.getProperty("file.separator")
                            + item.getName().substring(0,
                                    item.getName().length() - 4) + "."
                            + extension);
                    item.write(file);

                    receivedFiles.put(item.getFieldName(), file);
                    receivedContentTypes.put(item.getFieldName(),
                            item.getContentType());

                    response += "<file-" + cont + "-field>"
                            + item.getFieldName() + "</file-" + cont
                            + "-field>\n";
                    response += "<file-" + cont + "-name>" + item.getName()
                            + "</file-" + cont + "-name>\n";
                    response += "<file-" + cont + "-size>" + item.getSize()
                            + "</file-" + cont + "-size>\n";
                    response += "<file-" + cont + "-type>"
                            + item.getContentType() + "</file-" + cont
                            + "type>\n";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new UploadActionException(e);
                }
            }
        }
        ZipUtils appZip = new ZipUtils(userNumber + ".zip",
                ConfAppServer.getRealContextPath() + "/edoc/" + userNumber);
        appZip.generateFileList(new File(ConfAppServer.getRealContextPath()
                + "/edoc/" + userNumber));
        appZip.zipIt(userNumber + ".zip");
        f.delete();

        removeSessionFileItems(request);

        return "<response>\n" + response + "</response>\n";
    }
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968883/how-to-zip-a-folder-itself-using-java) you can find my `ZipUtils` class.

When I try to delete my folder, nothing happens. The delete() method doesn't work. Help me please!!
My question is how to add folder to zip and then delete this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.nio.file`. You won't have the hassle of manipulating the ZIP API yourself:

```
final Path pathToZip = Paths.get("path", "to", "your", "zip");

final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + pathToZip.toUri());
final Map<String, ?> env = Collections.singletonMap("create", "true");

try (
    final FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(uri, env);
) {
    // write files into the zip here.
    // See javadoc for java.nio.file.Files and FileSystem.getPath()
}
```

More details on how to use the API [here](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API).