# Zipping sub directories is zipping only content of sub directories but not the sub directories

Tags: java, file, zip

Below is the code I tried. it is zipping only content of the sub folder but not the folder
I need to zip all sub folders along with the contents. what i am doing wrong here. 
Example: I have a folder 'demo' inside demo folder  i have a, b, c folders. I want to zip a, b, c along with contents and zip should not include parent that is demo.

```
static void addDir(File dirObj, ZipOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        File[] files = dirObj.listFiles();
        byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[1024];

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
            addDir(files[i], out);
            continue;
          }
          FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
          System.out.println(" Adding: " + files[i].getName());
          out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));
          int len;
          while ((len = in.read(tmpBuf)) > 0) {
            out.write(tmpBuf, 0, len);
          }
          out.closeEntry();
          in.close();
        }
      }

    public static void zipFiles(File[] subd) {

        String zipFile = "test.zip";

        try {

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);

            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            for (File dir : subd) {

                addDir(dir, zos);

            }

            // close the ZipOutputStream
            zos.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error creating zip file: " + ioe);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833423/how-to-zip-the-content-of-a-directory-in-java/51833575#51833575) as a starting point (`out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));` needs to contain a path element, which is described in the linked example)

Comment: if I add path, it adds complete obsolute path,  i just need all  sub folders  and its contents inside the zip. I have explained with example

Comment: Read the linked example - it only adds relative paths (based on the source path)

Comment: Are you talking about this line   String name = srcFile.getPath();
                name = name.replace(rootPath.getPath(), "");

Comment: That’s the start of the basic idea (and just one approach)

Comment: Also why he has passed srcFolder two times in the argument, i am bit unclear

Comment: It's a recursive method, meaning that `addFolderToZip(srcFolder, srcFolder, zip);` is just seeding the initial pass

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code I did for zip files and directories with hierarchy and without hierarchy.
`zip.getHierarchy().equals("F")` part does the work you want to do.
In this code, you have to pass source file, destination, hierarchy (T/F) as arguments.
Additionally you may need a DTO class.

```
public static void Start() throws IOException{ 

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zip.getDestination());
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
    File fileToZip = new File(zip.getSourcePath());

        zipDirectory(fileToZip, fileToZip.getName(), zipOut);

    zipOut.close();
    fos.close();
}

public static void zipDirectory(File fileToZip, String fileName, ZipOutputStream zipOut) throws IOException {

    if (fileToZip.isDirectory()) {

        File[] children = fileToZip.listFiles();

        for (File childFile : children) {
            if(zip.getHierarchy().equals("T")) {
                zipDirectory(childFile, childFile.getPath(), zipOut);
            }else if(zip.getHierarchy().equals("F")){
                zipDirectory(childFile, childFile.getName(), zipOut);
            }
        }
        return; 
    }
    doZip(fileToZip,fileName,zipOut);
}

public static void doZip(File fileToZip,String fileName,ZipOutputStream zipOut) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
    zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    fis.close();
}
```