# How can I zip a directory with java.util.zip?

Tags: java, zip

I want to zip a folder into a zip file with `java.util.zip` tools.
I have already tried to read `org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip` in Gradle, but I cannot understand it at all.
Is there any code or opensource third-party tool that can zip a directory tree?

Comment: Edit: I guess I can handle it with `java.nio.file.Path` and `java.nio.file.Files.copy(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.Path)`, but I don't know how to write it detailedly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using ZipOutputStream to create zip.

```
 List<String> srcFiles = Arrays.asList("test1.txt", "test2.txt"); // List of all files
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("multiCompressed.zip");
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
    for (String srcFile : srcFiles) {
        File fileToZip = new File(srcFile);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName());
        zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        fis.close();
    }
    zipOut.close();
    fos.close();
```

Since you have to zip a folder,  you can read all the files inside folder and put inside list(Call method instead of hard coding file names in list ).

Below code I have written to read file from all folder and sub folder, You can make change in logic according to your requirements.

```
String path = "folderpath"
File dir = new File(path);
 List<String> srcFiles = populateFilesList(dir);
    private  List<String> populateFilesList(File dir) throws IOException {
        List filesListInDir = new ArrayList<String>();
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                filesListInDir.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            else
            {
                populateFilesList(file);
            }
        }
        return filesListInDir;
    }
```

Please try this and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Is this way available to copy a file tree correctly? For example: `E:\root\a.txt` will be zipped into entry `a` while `E:\root\c\d\e.jar` will be zipped into entry `c/d/e.jar` instead of `e.jar`. That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

What about use this lib [Zeroturnaround Zip library](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip)
Then you will zip your folder just a one line:

ZipUtil.pack(new File("D:\sourceFolder\"), new File("D:\generatedZipFile.zip"));

Comment: Plagiarizing [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985640/1831987) is not good form.

Comment: @VGR Duplicate questions call for duplicate answers