# How to zip a directory?

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to write a spring boot java code to compress a Directory using REST API call. I find many codes using plain Java, but I am unable to find a one in Spring boot Java. I tried the below code and its zipping the file but when i try to zip the directory it throws FilenotFound Exception. Could anyone please help me with a working code. I dont know where I am going wrong. I am a beginner to Spring boot.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/zip", produces="application/zip")
public void zipFiles(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
  response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"compressedfile.zip\"");
  ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
  ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
  files.add(new File("C:\\Pavan\\zipfolder"));  //(zip is working if(C:\\Pavan\\zipfolder\\dockerfile.txt)
  for (File file : files) {
    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);
    fileInputStream.close();
    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
  }
zipOutputStream.close();
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: can you check this answer ?
[how to zip a folder itself using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968883/how-to-zip-a-folder-itself-using-java)

Comment: This is for Plain java code right. I have been given requirement on Compressing a Directory using Spring boot Java Rest API. Could you please share any reference for the same.

Comment: Compressing a directory has nothing to do with Spring Boot or REST. It's just plain Java processing.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a directory to the `FileInputStream` constructor. This is not allowed, see [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream(java.io.File)). Instead you have to iterate over the files contained in this directory. See [Zipping and Unzipping in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress) for an example.